# How to building on pstricks the flowchart shape?

Tags: pstricks, loops

I need to building several flowcharts with `pstricks` and I have problems to get the symbol as the below. Can somebody help me?

```
\newcommand\psBucler[3]{%
\pspolygon(-1,0.1)(1.2,0.1)(1.2,1)(-1,1) %
\psline(-1,0.5)(0,0.5)%
\psline(0.1,0.1)(0.1,1) %
\rput[l](-0.9,0.75){#1} %
\rput[l](-0.9,0.27){#2} %
\rput[l](0.15,0.5){#3} }%
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `pstricks` for that. Here is  a very simple code that reproduces your image, and which can be inserted in pstricks code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand\Bucler[3]{%
\ensuremath{\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
  #1 &\multirow{2}{*}{\ensuremath{#3}}\\
\cline{1-1}
#2&\\
\hline
\end{array}}
}
\begin{document}

\Bucler{i = 1}{i + 1}{i\le 10}

\end{document}
```

[image]