# How to building the flowchart report shape?

Tags: pstricks, shapes, psmatrix

I am building un flowchart in `psmatrix` and need to generate the flowchart report(document) shape and I don't know as do it. The symbol is like in the picture below. Can somebody help me, please?

TIA.

[image]

Comment: So you don't want `tikz` ;-)

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)

Comment: Please make your questions a bit more distinguishable [How to building on pstricks the flowchart shape?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/234525)

Answer (score 4):

A solution with `pst-node`. With its `\psDefBoxNodes` command, which defines 12 nodes for any bounding box of an object, I define a `\mypsframe` command:

```
\documentclass[pdf, x11names]{article}%

 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc }
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{erewhon}

\usepackage{pst-node}%
\newcommand\mypsframe[1]{%
\psDefBoxNodes{T}{\psframebox[linestyle=none, framesep=10pt]{#1}}%
\psset{linecolor=VioletRed3, linewidth=1.2pt, angleA = -30,angleB = 150,arrows = -}
\psline(T:bl)(T:tl)(T:tr)(T:br)
\pccurve{c-c}(T:bl)(T:br)
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}
    \mypsframe{Print Text}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I know that you want `pstricks` answer. Hence this answer using `tikz` is just for academic purposes (please don't upvote).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
\tikzset{report/.style={tape, draw, tape bend top=none}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[report] {Print text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can adjust the bend quantity using `tape bend height=1cm` in

```
\tikzset{report/.style={tape, draw, tape bend top=none,tape bend height=1cm}
}
```

to get (exotic)

[image]

Change the curvature by

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols,positioning}
\tikzset{reporta/.style={tape,tape bend top=out and in, tape bend bottom=out and in, draw, tape bend height=1cm},
reportb/.style={tape,tape bend top=in and out, tape bend bottom=in and out, draw, tape bend height=1cm}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[reporta] (a) {Print text};
  \node[reportb, right = of a] {Print text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think an answer, if well written, deserves an upvote to honour the contribution to the site. Isn't providing alternative part of science?